# Highcharts: Format series names in tooltip

Tags: javascript, highcharts

I have multiple series on the same chart, and I'd like to use the tooltip formatter to make the series names look readable in the tooltip. At the moment, they're displayed in the form `Seriesonename` and `Seriestwoname`, but I'd like them to be displayed in the form `Series One Name` and `Series Two Name`. I'd still like to keep the tooltip in the same format of `Series One Name: 0.567`.

I've done something similar to this when formatting the chart labels, where I used the following code:

```
legend: {
  labelFormatter: function () {
    return {
      'Seriesonename': 'Series One Name',
      'Seriestwoname': 'Series Two Name'
    }[this.name];
  }
}
```

I've tried doing the same for the tooltip formatter, but I can't seem to get it to work. I suspect it's something to do with the fact that it's a shared tooltip, but I'm not 100% sure.

Any help would be greatly appreciated!

Comment: Why are you not setting the `name` attribute of the `Series` itself?

Comment: @HalvorStrand I'm not sure that I can. My data comes from another source, and I'm using a Highcharts wrapper to format everything, hence why I had to use the labelFormatter to sort out the series names in the legend.

Comment: But if you pre-process your data, you can do it once, before sending anything to the chart, rather than doing it every time you need to display the name.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

To do a similar approach to your `legend.labelFormatter` for the tooltip you could use `tooltip.formatter` or `tooltip.pointFormatter`, somewhat depending on how your chart is set up.

An example using the `tooltip.pointFormatter` could be ([JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/cdzacpqp/)):

```
tooltip: {
    pointFormatter: function() {
        var seriesNameConverter = {
            'Seriesonename': 'Series One Name',
            'Seriestwoname': 'Series Two Name'
        };

        return '<span style="color:{point.color}">\u25CF</span> '
            + seriesNameConverter[this.series.name] + ': <b>' + this.y + '</b><br/>';
    }
}
```

This is the default style of `tooltip.pointFormat` with your conversion in place of the series name.

Comment: I'm pretty sure this is exactly what I need, but it seems to have no effect whatsoever on the tooltip - there aren't any console errors either. `tooltip.formatter` did produce an error so I think I need to use `pointFormatter`.

Comment: You mean in your own code? Because the effect shown in the JSFiddle is what you need, correct?

Comment: Yeah, the JSFiddle is exactly what I want to achieve. I'm probably missing something obvious. Thanks for all of the help! :)